# NVD3 Stacked Area Charts update incorrectly on interacting with the Legend

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js, chain-builder

I have been working on the [chainbuilder platform](https://www.chain-builder.net/). This platform allows a user to create a chained workflow of how the data should be loaded and what charts should be displayed.

Underlying, we use NVD3 charts for displaying the visualizations. I have been facing some problems with the NVD3 Stacked Area chart. On my page I use two NVD3 Stacked Area charts.

These charts look as follows:
[image: This is what it looks like when it loads]

When I click on the Legend, lets say, I disable the plot for Caruaru from the legend, as seen in the image below. You can see the chart updates incorrectly.

[image: This is how the chart updates]

I went through the depth of its source code and tried to debug the workflow to see if the data changes or gets corrupted but could not find anything of that sort. I feel its some sort of a Race condition that is causing this problem.

I know its difficult to understand this without any code provided but its a dynamic system and would be difficult for me to explain the whole backend.

Can someone please give me an idea what could be the problem? Please let me know if you need more clarifications.

*Edit*

Following the basic code in my index.js

```
run: function(callback_id, elements, data) {
    $("head").append("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='nv.d3.css'>");
    $("head").append("<script src='d3.min.js'></script>");
    $("head").append("<script src='nv.d3.js'></script>");

    this.update(elements, data);
},


update: function(elements, data) {
if (typeof data.width != 'undefined')
    elements.css("width",data.width.value);

if (typeof data.height != 'undefined')
    elements.css("height",data.height.value);

if(typeof data.yaxis != 'undefined')
    elements.attr("yaxis",data.yaxis.value);

if(typeof data.options != 'undefined')
        elements.attr("options", data.options.value);

if (typeof data.value != 'undefined') {
    if(($(elements[0]).children().length>0) && (elements[0].firstChild.nodeName.toLowerCase()=='text')) 
        elements[0].removeChild(elements[0].firstChild);

    nv.addGraph(function() {
        var parsed = d3.csv.parseRows(data.value.value);
        var chart = nv.models.stackedAreaChart();

        chart.xAxis
            .axisLabel(parsed[0][0])
            .showMaxMin(false);

        chart.yAxis
            .axisLabel(elements.attr("yaxis"))
            .tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'))
            .showMaxMin(true);

        chart
            .options(JSON.parse(elements.attr("options")));

         chart.margin().left = 80;

        d3.select(elements[0])
            .datum(createdata(parsed))
            .transition().duration(500)
            .call(chart);


        elements.resize(function() {
            chart.yAxis
                .axisLabel(elements.attr("yaxis"))
                .tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));
            chart.xAxis
                .axisLabel(parsed[0][0]);
            chart
                .options(JSON.parse(elements.attr("options")));
            chart
                .width(elements.width())
                .height(elements.height());

            chart.update();
        });

        return chart;
    });

    function createdata(parsed) {
        var columns = [];

        for(i in parsed)
            columns[i-1] = parsed[i][0];

        var data = new d3.range(1,parsed[0].length).map(function(d,i) {
            return {
                key: parsed[0][i+1],
                values: new d3.range(1,parsed.length-1).map( function(f,j) {
                    return {
                        y: +parsed[j+1][i+1],
                        x: +columns[j]
                    }
                })
            };
        });

        return data;        
    }
} else 
    if($(elements[0]).children().length==0){
        var width=$(elements[0]).width();
        var height=$(elements[0]).height();
        elements[0].innerHTML='<text text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="central" x="'+width/2+'" y="'+height/2+'" fill="black">No data for force directed graph</text>';
    }

elements.trigger('resize');
```

}

Comment: is your second chart titled with "storage at each time step in m3 " working fine ?

Comment: The second chart sometimes updates correctly and sometimes it doesn't... I dont know whats happening.

Comment: can you share your code ?

Comment: @sandyJoshi I have added the code snippet above. Do check and let me know if you can help?

Comment: When and How many times `run` function gets called ? Any chances for being the the arguments of `run` same whenever it will be called again ?

Comment: `run` will get called only once by each chart when it is loaded.